# Visual Studio unable to run .NET Core tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, testing

Using the latest version of Visual Studio, I'm unable to run any tests in the tests explorer. The error message in the `Tests` output window is:

```
Testhost process exited with error: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.0 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=2.2.0&arch=x86&rid=win10-x86
. Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
[17/12/2019 5:46:13.908 PM] ========== Run aborted: 0 tests run (0:00:00.2418036) ==========
```

So it's suggestion that I need to have .net core 2.2 installed but it cannot find it. It can only find 3.1.

Let's confirm that ....

```
C:\Users\justi>dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.100
 Commit:    cd82f021f4

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.18362
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.0
  Commit:  65f04fb6db

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.604 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.701 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.802 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.204 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.206 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  <snip snip>
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  <snip snip>
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  <snip snip>
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  <snip snip>
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  <snip snip>
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

So it *feels* like I have 2.2.0 installed, as it's listed in the list of the many versions installed.

#### Edit

Notice this bit (emphasis mine):

> - The following frameworks were found:
>       3.1.0 at [C:\Program Files **(x86)**\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

It looks like it's got 3.1.0 installed into .. `x86` while the rest of the sdk's are installed under `Program Files` (x64 bit versions).

Why does it say this?

#### Edit 2:

- xUnit
- xUnit VS runner nuget is also 'installed'.
- Visual Studio 16.4.1

Comment: I had a similar issue fixed by closing and reopening all VS windows. I had many open solutions and don't know what was cached where that caused this issue. Maybe this helps

Comment: Thanks heaps @Emad for the suggestion. I've also just tried that (closed _all_ instances) and reopened just this one. Nope -> still erroring.

Comment: Some times problems with Tests in visual studio is fixed by changing to x64 architecture. Could you try it? Tests->TestSettings->Default Processor architecture

Comment: What kind if tests are you use? There are a lot of frameworks. And if it is not MsTests,For example for XUnit, you should install TestRunners.

Comment: added more info to the OP.

Comment: @TemaTre yep - u _sorta_ got it. It was set to x86 and when i switched it over to x64 ... it worked. But why?

Comment: I've tried opening up another totally different solution .. and it's defaulted to x86 BUT it's working and locating the x64 sdk because the tests all run (with x86 ticked) and also this is logged to the TESTS output window: `xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.1 (64-bit .NET Core 4.6.28207.03)` ... so it's like it's "auto detecting" based on something?

Comment: Change from CPU x86 to x64 …  `Test > Process architecture for anyCPU projects > x64`

Comment: It is strange for me Too. .Net is compiled to IL and not depend on architecture. May be it is caused by architecture of VisualStudio. So VS is always x86. Microsoft says that it is not easy to rewrite as x64. (May be sometimes we can install VS x64). So x86 programs by default loads DLLs from x86. May be this is reason of problem.

Comment: _It looks like it's got 3.1.0 installed into .. x86 while the rest of the sdk's are installed under Program Files (x64 bit versions)_ This can only happen if you installed the SDK yourself from the website and picked the wrong version. VS Installer will always install the x64 version when updating Visual Studio editions (minor releases)

Answer (score 26):

Change from CPU x86 to x64 … Test > Process architecture for anyCPU projects > x64

[image]

Comment: Yep - this got my tests working again .. but I'm trying to figure out _how_ and _why_ this all started, in the first place.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I don't know why, but the Processor Architecture setting must have been reset when I reinstalled or upgraded Visual Studio (I've done both recently).

Comment: In the default VS2019 configuration this option is located under the gear icon in Test Explorer. I tried to edit this answer but it looks like it's going to be rejected.

Comment: I'm guessing what's going on here is VS 16.4 ships with .NET Core 3.1, which for some people may be the first 32-bit SDK that has been installed. I suspect even if x86 is checked (not sure if this is the default) it might run with 64-bit SDKs if no 32-bit SDKs are found. Either that or the default for that setting was changed to x86 when VS upgraded.

Comment: Seems like after version `16.0.1` of `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` it looks for shared package `dotnetcoreapp` only in `C:\Program Files x86\dotnet\shared` not checking `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared`.

Answer (score 8):

This can sometimes happen, when you upgraded your test projects but didn't upgrade the Test SDK. This can also happen if you upgrade Visual Studio but don't have the latest test sdks referenced.

In your test project's `.csproj`file you should find something along the lines of

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.7.0" />
```

in your `testproject.csproj`.

These are usually in sync with Visual Studio releases, so the latest Visual Studio is 16.4. Try upgrading that reference to match your version of Visual Studio, i.e.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
```

for the latest stable release or

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0-preview-20191115-01" />
```

for the latest Preview.

Another source of this error may be, that your project is .NET Core 3.x project, but your unit test project is still .NET Core 2.2. Make sure they both use the same version of .NET Core

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 5):

I too had this issue.  The error displayed in the Tests Output.

[image]

Error message snippet:

> Test data store opened in 0.153 sec.
> ---------- Starting test discovery for requested test run ---------- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException:
> Testhost process exited with error: It was not possible to find any
> compatible framework version The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App',
> version '2.1.0' was not found.
>
> - The following frameworks were found:
>   3.1.9 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] You can resolve the problem
>   by installing the specified framework and/or SDK. The specified
>   framework can be found at:
> - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.1.0&arch=x86&rid=win81-x86
>   . Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.ThrowOnTestHostExited(Boolean
>   testHostExited)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1
>   sources, String runSettings)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.DiscoverTests(DiscoveryCriteria
>   discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler)
>   ========== Test discovery aborted: 0 Tests found in 1.4 sec ========== Executing all tests in file: ConfigurationTests.cs
>   ---------- Starting test run ----------
>   ========== Test run finished: 0 Tests run in 123.4 ms (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) ==========

The issue occurred after installing .NET Core SDK 3.1.x.  This change must of done something to Visual Studio Test settings.

Installations at (x86):

[image]

Installations at (x64):

[image]

I fixed it without any changes to the solution or project file.  In my Test Explorer I chose the Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects.  I changed it from x86 to x64.

[image]

Note: all of my .NET Core installations are x64.  However, for some reason only 3.1.x existed in x86.  My test project's Target framework is .NET Core 2.1, so to run the tests it needed to look in the x64 folder path.

How installations look from Add or Remove Programs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

commands `dotnet run`, `dotnet test`... etc they all use latest dotnet version they can find, this version can be validated by `dotnet --info`as you have already done and in your case latest installed is 3.1.0. If you want to run `dotnet` of different version you need to create global.json file as described here [Select the .NET Core version to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection)

From linked resource

> When you run an SDK command, the SDK uses the latest installed version.
>
> `dotnet` searches for a global.json file interactively reverse-navigating the path upward from the current working directory
>
> `dotnet`uses the SDK specified in the first global.json found

just create global.json in you solution folder and define desired correct sdk version

Answer (score 0):

Some times problems with Tests in visual studio is fixed by changing to x64 architecture. Could you try it? Tests->TestSettings->Default Processor architecture.

One more point is, default loading incorrect DLL. So, visual studio is generate by I faced with something like this:

```
<Choose>
<When Condition="('$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '') and '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v3.5'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
  </ItemGroup>
</When>
<Otherwise>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

So, the problem is in Otherwise. I replace it to:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

And all works correct. May be in your project you has something like this.

Comment: it is *.csproj file

Comment: Is it helps for you?

Comment: Problems with superseding the **v10** of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` have been going on forever. I concur this does work with the QualityTools but it conflicts with OP using the xUnit.net VSTest Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Adding specific .NET core version to Build pipeline solve my problem.
Find specific .NET core version [Here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2)
[image]